# Watermarking video from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, watermark, video-watermarking

does anyone know how to watermark video from the Linux command line using a simple tool?

Watermarking in ffmpeg isn't supported in the current version, and requires a custom compile.

Max.

Comment: Suggest closing and moving to superuser.

Comment: +1 unless he's planning to write his own app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -y -i 'inputFile.mpg' -vhook '/usr/lib/vhook/watermark.so -f /home/user/logo.gif'
```

Make note of the "-vhook" parameter; watermark.so path may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to do this is updating ffmpeg to the newest version and adding the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) video filter:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):(main_h-overlay_h)" watermark.mp4
```

This also gives you more options on where to place the watermark as well. For example, if you wanted to place the watermark in the center of the video you would use:

```
-filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w/2):(main_h-overlay_h/2)"
```