# How to Watermark videos with FFMPEG commands

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, watermark

i need to watermark a video file.
i have FF-MPEG Linux server and ff-mpeg is installed by default
plz reply me the command of watermarking for below details
1. The source file is Input.mp4
2. the Target file is Output.mp4
3. the watermark file Watermark.png

please send me the Linux commands.
is there anyone know, please reply soon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watermarking video from the Linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033401/watermarking-video-from-the-linux-command-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add transparent watermark in center of a video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918907/how-to-add-transparent-watermark-in-center-of-a-video-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://ksloan.net/watermarking-videos-from-the-command-line-using-ffmpeg-filters/) it should be something like:

```
ffmpeg -i Input.mp4 -i Watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" Output.mp4
```

10:10 are the coordinates from the top and from the right for the overlay. (In this example 10 pixels from the top and 10 pixels from the right)

Comment: For the overlay, I found `overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2` as centering the image over the video. This was from the duplicate question referenced in a comment above.

Comment: what will be the code line for batch videos in linux